# how generate project.assets.json

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I create a new .NET Standard project and try to build without any code added, I get

> "Assets file 'E:\Storage\Google Drive\My Content\My Documents\My LC
>   TECH\Projects\LC Development\LC.Assets\obj\project.assets.json' not
>   found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file."

I've tried to run **dotnet restore** but without luck.

How to create the file or remove reference to it?

I use Visual Studio 2019 preview, but had same error when using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 4):

turned out that this was caused by an faulty installation of .net core sdk.

installed everything again and it started working